# Error while saving a form in a WinForm app

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio

I migrated an old windows forms sample app to Visual Studio 2015, now sometimes when I modify something in Form designer, I can't save it, it prompts this error (HistogramDemo is my app name):

`Could not load file or assembly 'HistogramDemo, Version=1.0.5729.30338, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Answer (score 0):

AVoid utilize the four last digits of VERSION - it causes some malfunction in Visual Studio, related to locate and upgrade settings - perhaps your problem.

If not so, the problem can be related to a control in usage within your form. Compile your application either in DEBUG and RELEASE modes.

Check your application folder to see if there is any kind of restriction that could deny access for VS2015 to create folder and/or write files.

Good luck!

Comment: You may also delete the .SUO file and check if VS2015 recreate it - but before do this, make a backup of the entire application folder (a ZIP for instance).